# New Programmer Issue: Unable to update SublimeText3 on Mac OS X with the latest version of Python (version 3.7.3)

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am new to programming, so I, unfortunately, am unsure how to resolve the following issue. (Please note that I have watched multiple videos and read several articles to try to resolve this issue before asking this question, however, have been unsuccessful in finding a solution. This issue is for Mac OS X.)

Issue:
In SublimeText 3, I am receiving the following message after attempting to install Python 3.7.3. (Message was populated after viewing "Console -> Tools -> Build System" in Sublime.)

Message:

```
Starting Out/print(Hello': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 2]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/williamtubberville/Desktop/Coding Files/Starting 
Out/print("Hello Python world!").py"]
[dir: /Users/williamtubberville/Desktop/Coding Files/Starting Out]
[path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Steps I have taken to setup Python 3.7.3 and test:

- Determine path of python 3.7.3:
  Step 1. Open Terminal: Command + Space + "terminal"
  Step 2. Check python3 version: "python3 --version"
  Step 3. Check python3 path: "type -a python3"
  Result: python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
  python3 is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
  python3 is /usr/local/bin/python3
- Create a Python file type to test in Sublime:
  Step 4. Exact code used for the test:

> ```
> import sys
>  print(sys.version)
>  print("Hello Python world!")
> ```

Step 5. Save as .py file on the desktop and moved to my organized coding file also on the desktop.

- In Sublime install latest version of Python3:
  Step 6. Check "Python Box" in Tools -> Build System
  Step 7. Tools -> Build Systems -> New Build Systems
  Step 8. Erase line of code in default.
  Step 9. Changed "Cmd" to: /usr/local/bin/python3
  Exact Line of Code Used:

> ```
> {
>  "cmd":["/usr/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file"],"selector":"source.python", 
>  "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line([0-9]+)"
>  }
> ```

After rebooting Sublime, I attempted to test Python with Tools -> Build Systems -> Python. (I believe there should be a Python3 version below Python, but it isn't there.) After running Python with Tools -> Build, I received that message above.

Any help would be appreciated as I have spent several hours trying to resolve. Thank you for your time and support. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Best,
Will

Comment: By which name did you save the file after step 9?

Comment: In the error output, the `shell_cmd` line shows you exactly what command Sublime tried to execute, and in that command your filename is `print("Hello Python world!").py`, which may not be valid. Try renaming the file to something conventional like `hello.py` and see if that works.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thank you for the response. Your issue resolved my problem in terms of the program running Python with no error message, however the program is still showing as the default version 2.7.10. Here is the response after running Tools -> Build.2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]
Hello Python world!
[Finished in 0.1s]

Comment: @Williamct That's because the default build system for Python in Sublime executes `python` as a command. Since it's not running what you expect, either the command is `python3` instead, or the path is set up to find the system version of `python` before your own.

Comment: @OdatNurd Thanks for the response but I'm still unsure how to resolve. I believe for the default, you are referring to the drop down menu under tools, build systems, in which Python3 should be an option below Python. Python3 is not an option on that list, only the original Python. If you would be able to provide a simple step-by-step solution, or potential other issues, I would appreciate it. I have been trying to resolve for the last few days. Also, I was unsure if this may be the issue, but does "$file" need to be replaced with an actual file, or do I paste as is; only changing cmd. Thanks

Comment: What you have above in your question is more or less correct. Your steps 7 through 9 outline what I would suggest, which is making a build system that runs `python3` instead. However, for step 6 you want to check the build system you just made; it appears in the menu under the same name as what you saved the build system as. The `$file` is correct; it expands out to the name of the current file when the build executes.